# How to hide folder "Search Paths" in a Texlipse project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, latex

I am using Eclipse/Texlipse plugin and if I create a new project Texclipse
automatically creates a folder called "Search Paths". You are not possible to do
a right click on that folder to get to the properties etc. I was wondering whether it is
possible to somehow hide that folder as it just includes the paths for the latex compilers etc.

Answer (score 1):

The "Search Paths" folder is only virtual and is not created by TeXlipse on the file system. Furthermore, it is solely shown in the "Project explorer" view. You can use Eclipse's "Navigator" view instead, which is similar to the "Project explorer".